# SQL orders by weekdays, weeks and years

Tags: mysql, sql

I am beginner at SQL programming and I am trying to solve this exercise. I need to count how many orders have been placed on each day of week, order them by days (from Sunday to Saturday) and sort them by appropriate weeks and years. I have written this statement so far, but I don't know how to count orders placed in particular day of appropriate week and how to convert numbers of days to their names. Thank you for your help.

```
SELECT orderNumber, orderDate, YEAR(orderDate) AS year,
       WEEKOFYEAR(orderDate) AS week, DAYOFWEEK(orderDate) AS day
FROM orders
GROUP BY year, week, day
ORDER BY year, week, day
```

Result (part):
[image]

Comment: What's your DBMS? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, ...?

Comment: When you order by the order date it is automatically order by year/week/day :-) And then add `count(*)` (or `count(orderNumber)`) to get the count per day.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use alias's in the order by

try

```
order by  YEAR(orderDate) , WEEKOFYEAR(orderDate),DAYOFWEEK(orderDate)
```

Comment: No, you can use.